# pass the value to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to pass the value from the Ajax code to the database as this program is to show the details of the user, but there is an error in the code in passing the value. What can I do now?

```js
function showUser() {
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if (!httpRequest) {
    alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
    return false;
  }
  var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;

  httpRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost/cart/guser.php?id=" + id + "&rand=" + , true);
  httpRequest.send();
}

function alertContents() {
  if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
    }
  }
  var id = document.getElementById('id').value;

}
```

```html
<form>
  enter digit :
  <input type="text" id="id" name="id" />
  <br />
  <input type='button' onclick='showUser(this.value)' value='select' />

</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b>
</div>
```

below code is for guser.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "cart";
 
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


mysqli_select_db('cart',$con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>email</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are LOTS of problems. The button doesn't have a value, so `this.value` will be empty. You're calling `showUser()` with an argument, but it doesn't take any parameters. You have nothing after `"&rand" +`. In `alertContents` you set the `id` variable but you never use it.

Comment: there is no sense in using `form` and `ajax` at the same time because page gets refreshed when form is submitted and also `submit` button doesn't have any value.

Comment: @saurabh sharma can you upload also code of your `guser.php` file,then I will upload full correcting code in the answers.

Comment: @VikasBhandari yeah sure ... you can see that in the question now

Comment: @saurabh sharma what is `$_GET['q']` in `guser.php`.Should'nt it be `$_GET['id']` and why are You passing `rand` variable if you are not using it in guser.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

Add in head:`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

you have to type person id in inputbox and user info in texthint div:

you will get id in guser.php  of user from post and run query.and echo user info into guser.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser($id){

    $("#email").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/cart/guser.php",
        data:'keyword='$id,
        success: function(data){
            $("#txtHint").html(data);

         }
        });
    });
}
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your code have lots of problems
code of new `html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  enter digit :
  <input type="text" id="id" name="id" onkeyup='showUser(this.value)'/>
  <br />


</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b>
</div> 

<script>
function showUser(id) {
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if (!httpRequest) {
    alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
    return false;
  }
else
{

        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
            }
        };
        httpRequest.open("GET", "localhost/cart/guser.php?id=" + id, true);
        httpRequest.send();
}

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and code of new `guser.php` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "cart";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


mysqli_select_db('cart',$con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>email</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!!..Comment for further queries

Answer (score 0):

Either you should remove the `,` from `httpRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost/cart/guser.php?id="+id+"&rand="+,true);` jsut before `true` to make `rand=true`

or remove the `+` from the url just after `&rand="`

Comment: Why should he remove the comma? That's needed to separate the URL from the `async` flag.

Comment: no.
in that case he should remove `+` 
check his url again
`"http://localhost/cart/guser.php?id=" + id + "&rand=" + , true`

after `rand="` there is a `+` which points nowhere.

i guess it should be `rand=true` to generate random data or whatever

Comment: Yes, there's something missing after `+`, but `true` is the third argument to `open()`.